# Triggering wx.EVT_COMBOBOX after programatically changing ComboBox selection?

Tags: combobox, wxpython, wxwidgets

As per the title, is there any way to programatically change the selected item in a `ComboBox` and have it raise an event?

I am setting the selected item using `myComboBox.SetSelection(index)`, but this doesn't raise the `wx.EVT_COMBOBOX` event.

Comment: Seems bizarre to me that wxWidgets doesn't trigger the event from `SetSelection`. Swing does that kind of thing, and it's very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use C++ version of wxWidget. Look up documentation on these two functions:

void wxPostEvent(wxEvtHandler *dest, wxEvent& event)
void AddPendingEvent(wxEvent& event)

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a function I could call (I believe there's one for WinForms using C#), but wx.PostEvent works fine. Thanks for the poinetr!